# Where i can find tool for database in Anroid Studio?

Tags: android, database, android-studio, kotlin

I was trying to create a database in Android Studio but i didn't find proper option for this.
I mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1E6u.png) tool (it's a Intellij IDEA).

Maybe there is another way to create database in Android Studio ?

Comment: Room database is pretty much standard for Android these days
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: You didn't find anything at that link?

Comment: @IvanWooll no, this link helped me, lot's pf thanks!